# setState doesn't work after submitting the form

Tags: reactjs, forms, function, react-hooks, state

I'm new to React JS and now I'm trying to learn hooks in function components. Here is my code:

App

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import AddPlayerForm from "./components/AddPlayerForm";

const App = () => {
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState("");
  const handleAddPlayer = (player) => {
    setPlayer(player);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h3>Player: {player}</h3>
      <AddPlayerForm addPlayer={handleAddPlayer} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Form:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddPlayerForm = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleValueChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.addPlayer(e.target.value);
    e.target.reset();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          onChange={handleValueChange}
          value={value}
          className="form-control form-control-lg"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add player"
        />
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddPlayerForm;
```

So I'm trying to provide submitted value from the from to App component but for some reason nothing changes in `<h3>Player: {player}</h3>` after clicking submit. Could you please tell me where I made a mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `AddPlayerForm` component, you're using the `useState` hook to store the value of the input in `value` every time the input changes. So, in the handleSubmit method, instead of passing `e.target.value`, you can pass `value`.

Also, if you want to reset the input after submitting, you can call `setValue("")`.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const AddPlayerForm = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleValueChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.addPlayer(value);
    setValue(""); // To reset the input
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <input
          onChange={handleValueChange}
          value={value}
          className="form-control form-control-lg"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add player"
        />
      </div>
      <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default AddPlayerForm;
```

The React docs has a section on handling forms.
https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

Also, this article on uncontrolled components might be helpful.
https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 2):

You should submit the `value` of the state:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.value); // undefined

  // value from useState
  props.addPlayer(value);
};
```

Also, `e.target.reset()` won't work because your `input` component is a controlled component (use of `value={value}`), therefore in order to reset you need to reset the state:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(e.target.value); // undefined

  // value from useState
  props.addPlayer(value);

  // not e.target.reset()
  setValue('');
};
```

See [Controlled vs Uncontrolled components](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#controlled-vs-uncontrolled-components)

[image: Edit Q-62979669-ResetTarget]

Answer (score 2):

Try This. Pass the `value` present in your state to `addPlayer`

```
 const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.addPlayer(value);
    e.target.reset();
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your handleSubmit function to:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
props.addPlayer(value);
e.target.reset();
```

};

because the variable value contains the name of the player.